# Printing XmlElement names in PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell

I have a XML document:

```
<Root>
  <ItemA Name="1" />
  <ItemB Name="2" />
  <ItemC Name="3" />
</Root>
```

and a powershell script accessing data from that document. I need to iterate by the children of Root and print the element names of its children. Example:

```
$xml = [xml](gc MyXmlFile.xml);

$xml.Root.Name 
# prints "Root"

$xml.Root.ChildNodes | foreach { $_.Name } 
# prints 1 2 3 because Item(A|B|C) have an attribute named "Name"
# I need to print ItemA ItemB ItemC
```

**Update**: As MrKWatkins correctly pointed out below in this case I could use the LocalName property instead. However this will not work if I'm using namespaces of if I also have a LocalName attribute in my XML. I would like to know if exists a solution for this problem that always works no matter the XML file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$xml.Root | gm -MemberType property | select Name
```

Comment: Bah, I was too slow. I'll delete mine :)

Comment: @EBGreen- I love the "purely phenomenological solution" part :)

Comment: Yeah, I know it works, and I understand why it works. I just don't understand why it needs to work this way. It feels dirty :)

Answer (score 4):

You could use the LocalName property instead as you're not using namespaces with your XML:

```
$xml.Root.ChildNodes | foreach { $_.LocalName }
```

Comment: Thanks, that solves my particular problem. I'm still leaving the question unanswered to see if someone comes up with a more "generic" solution (one the would also work if I was using namespaces or had a LocalName attribute too)

Answer (score 2):

While manoljlds solution works for getting all element names of children in a parent node, it doesn't help for single elements or when you want to use the element name with the element. I ended up just using Reflection.

```
$xml.Root.ChildNodes | % { $_.GetType().GetProperty("Name").GetValue($_, $null); }
```

Answer (score 1):

be careful, if there is an attribute whose name is "name" it will return the value of the attribute, not the element. To guarantee you get the correct value you can use get_name() method but you need to watchout for null since you are using a method.

example:

```
([xml]"<myelement name='attributename'/>").myelement.name
```

output:

```
attributename
```

using get_Name()

```
([xml]"<myelement name='attributename'/>").myelement.get_name()
```

output:

```
myelement
```

Also remember you can use a method on an array, but you need to be careful because if an array item is null it will fail.

e.g. @($elem1,$null,$Elemen2).get_name() will throw an error.